# ckeditor image upload working correctly in my system and other systems in my office ,but not working in client system

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ckeditor, ckeditor.net

I am having the Ck Editor version 4.4.6.

In that I add an extra plugin for uploading images.

That system's ck editor image upload plugin is working correctly in my system and other systems in my office, in all browsers (IE,Firefox,and Chrome), but it is not working in the client's system in any browser.

I have checked all the browser settings of the client but it was all the same as in our browser settings.

This is the script for add fileupload url browser

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
         CKEDITOR.replace('<%=ckeditjncms.ClientID %>',
  { filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'http://joinbw.in/Upload.ashx' }); //path to “Upload.ashx”
         });
    </script>
```

And the `upload.ashx` is:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Upload" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Upload : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        HttpPostedFile uploads = context.Request.Files["upload"];
       string CKEditorFuncNum = context.Request["CKEditorFuncNum"];  
       string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads.FileName);
       Guid g;
       g = Guid.NewGuid();
       file = g + file;
       uploads.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath("CKEditorImages/" + file));
     //  uploads.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\CKEditorImages\\" + file);        
       string url = "http://joinbw.in/CKEditorImages/" + file;
       context.Response.Write("<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + CKEditorFuncNum + ", \"" + url + "\");</script>");
       //context.Response.Clear(); 
       context.Response.End(); 
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an IIS configuration issue or a file permission issue. Ensure that your webserver has write permissions.

Comment: Try writing a file with static content in your code to verify file write works

Comment: is there any problem in passing ''http: //joinmbw.in/CKEditorImages/ '' instead of ''http: //www.joinmbw.in/CKEditorImages/''

Comment: Could be. Depends on your DNS configuration. Joinmbw.in without www might not be present.

Comment: yeh, you are correct, I found the problem in joinmbw.in present with www at prefix... the binding of url in client system was present with www. After removing that it works fine.... Thank you..